# Changing Properties at runtime

Tags: spring

Can we change the properties of BasicDataSource in spring applicationContext.xml such as url, driverClassName at runtime ?

My application needs to take dynamic URL's from user interface and use them to update or remove data

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should not use a static aproach for your problem. What you declare in applicationContext.xml it's intended to be static. 
What you seem to implement is a kind of connection manager depending on user inputs, it is a dynamic connection aproach.

In this case you should instantiate each connection on user demand not when application context is loaded. You can instantiate a diferente Datasource using for example [C3P0](http://sourceforge.net/projects/c3p0/) and pass it to your DAO or Connection manager (that can be already declared and instantiated on your context).

Answer (score 0):

A solution could be to publish the dynamic configuration on a web server, and include the url of this configuration in your files.